# UIScrollview calculation of new CGRect after ZoomToRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

My problem is i am not able to get the exact `CGRect` value after zooming for zooming in `UIScrollview` i am using `zoomToRect` method of `UIScrollview`. while zooming i am setting the `contentOffset` property.

**Code follows:**

```
if(image != nil) {

        CGSize zoomViewSize = image.frame.size;


        CGSize scrollViewSize = self.bounds.size;

        if(zoomViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width) {
            anOffset.x = -(scrollViewSize.width - zoomViewSize.width) / 2.0;
        }

        if(zoomViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height) {
            anOffset.y = -(scrollViewSize.height - zoomViewSize.height) / 2.0;
        }
    }
super.contentOffset = anOffset;
```

after zooming i am setting the content inset property so that image comes in the center. for content inset the code is given below.

```
-(void)zoomtorect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated {

[super zoomtorect:rect animated:YES];


CGFloat pageWidth = image.image.size.height;



         CGSize imageSize = rect.size;
         CGSize zoomedImageSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * 0.2, imageSize.height * 0.2);
         CGSize pageSize = self.bounds.size;

         //scLayer.frame = rect;
         UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
         if (pageSize.width > zoomedImageSize.width) {
             inset.left = (pageSize.width - zoomedImageSize.width) / 2;
             inset.right = inset.left;
         }
         if (pageSize.height > zoomedImageSize.height) {
             inset.top = (pageSize.height - zoomedImageSize.height) / 2;
             inset.bottom = inset.top;
         }

         self.contentInset = inset;
}
```

this code shifts my image view  between screen. Every thing works fine here. My problem is i have to show only zoom portion of the `imageView` rest will be black. For calculating the zoomed area i am doing the following calculation.

```
CGSize imageSize = rect.size;
    CGSize zoomedImageSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * scroll.maximumZoomScale, imageSize.height *scroll.maximumZoomScale);
    CGSize pageSize = scroll.bounds.size;

    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    if (pageSize.width > zoomedImageSize.width) {
        inset.left = (pageSize.width - zoomedImageSize.width) / 2;
        inset.right = inset.left;
    }
    if (pageSize.height > zoomedImageSize.height) {
        inset.top = (pageSize.height - zoomedImageSize.height) / 2;
        inset.bottom = inset.top;
    }

    CGRect zoomRect = [scroll convertRect:rect fromView:image];

    CGRect zoomRect1 = CGRectMake(inset.left, inset.top+50, zoomRect.size.width, zoomRect.size.height);
```

this `zoomRect1` is the zoomed area of the image this value is not exact what i am seeing in the screen. some where i am doing calculation mistake please help me out. But i am not getting the exact value of the zoomed image area.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer my answer. I am setting the zoom when user double taps the image @Gyanendra

Answer (score 1):

Use this.. **Works Perfectly**

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(isAlreadyZoomed)
    {
        CGPoint Pointview = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        CGFloat newZoomscal = 3.0;
        CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrollContainer.bounds.size;
        CGFloat width = scrollViewSize.width/newZoomscal;
        CGFloat height = scrollViewSize.height /newZoomscal;
        CGFloat xPos = Pointview.x-(width/2.0);
        CGFloat yPos = Pointview.y-(height/2.0);
        CGRect rectTozoom=CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        [self.scrollContainer zoomToRect:rectTozoom animated:YES];
        [self.scrollContainer setZoomScale:3.0 animated:YES];
        isAlreadyZoomed = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [self.scrollContainer setZoomScale:1.0 animated:YES];
        isAlreadyZoomed = YES;
    }
}
```

`isAlreadyZoomed` is a `BOOL` value

Comment: thanks for the answer. My problem is i want to get the cgrect value after the zoom. i call the method zoomtorect:rect after zoom the original value of rect is changed to some value depending on the zoomscale. i want to get the value of the new cgrect after the zoom. as i am doing setting the contentinset value for shifting the image to the middle of the screen i am not able to get the cgrect value after the zoom. Please help me

Comment: you will get the newzoom rect in my answer where you can write your zoomscale too. I had put statically 3.0 but place your zoomscale in the line  CGFloat newZoomscal = yourzoomscale;

Comment: suppose the CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20,20,300,300) when i call [zoomtorect:rect animated:YES] this method does not return the rect value after the zoom. so how can i calculate the zoomed rect with respect to original rect.I setting the contentInset also so i ma not able to get the zoomed rect. for getting zoomRect we multiply the original rect with the scrollView zoomScale but i am setting the contentInset property of the UIScrollView so i am not able to get the zoomRect with respect to original rect